# Error reading file: uiskin.json in Netbeans using LibGDX (Trying to create a TextField in LibGDX)

Tags: java, json, netbeans, libgdx, textfield

Hello good day everyone I've been trying to add a textfield but I am getting an error after another

I created the project, tested it using desktop,html, androidstudio, making use of Shaperenderer, another using an image other than badlogic.jpg and ScreenAdapter and they worked fine... I did all this tests before trying to create a TextField with libgdx, for some reason when testing I realize my core folder doesn't have an assests folder and the "core/assests" folder is at desktop\build\resources\main and it works properly but I am not sure if this could be a problem, as mentioned before I can use images from desktop, android and html if a place them there

Ok so now to the explanation:

This is the code in the class

```
public class SelectImages extends ScreenAdapter implements InputProcessor{
    
    GameClass game;
    
    TextureAtlas atlasFile = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.atlas.txt"));
    Skin uiSkin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin3.json"));
    
    Table table = new Table();
    
    

    public SelectImages(GameClass game) {
        this.game = game;
        uiSkin.addRegions(atlasFile);
        TextField txtFieldNum = new TextField("", uiSkin);
        txtFieldNum.setPosition(24,73);
        txtFieldNum.setSize(88, 14);
        table.add(txtFieldNum);
        
    }
```

I tried this [LibGDX - Error reading file: uiskin.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31574577/libgdx-error-reading-file-uiskin-json)
removing **com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextTooltip$TextTooltipStyle:**

I got the json file from a github website it was as BitmapFont, Color.... Changed manually to
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont,com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color...

Also created one using the same code.. just open a txt and saved as .json

The whole Json file looks like:

```
{
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: { default-font: { file: default.fnt.txt } },
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color: {
    green: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 1, r: 0 },
    white: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1, r: 1 },
    red: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 1 },
    black: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 0 },
    gray: { a: 1, b: 0.8, g: 0.8, r: 0.8 },
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$TintedDrawable: {
    dialogDim: { name: white, color: { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 0.45 } },
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button$ButtonStyle: {
    default: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round, disabled: default-round },
    toggle: { parent: default, checked: default-round-down }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
    default: { parent: default, font: default-font, fontColor: white, disabledFontColor: gray },
    toggle: { parent: default, checked: default-round-down, downFontColor: red }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane$ScrollPaneStyle: {
    default: { vScroll: default-scroll, hScrollKnob: default-round-large, background: default-rect, hScroll: default-scroll, vScrollKnob: default-round-large }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SelectBox$SelectBoxStyle: {
    default: {
        font: default-font, fontColor: white, background: default-select,
        scrollStyle: default,
        listStyle: { font: default-font, selection: default-select-selection }
    }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SplitPane$SplitPaneStyle: {
    default-vertical: { handle: default-splitpane-vertical },
    default-horizontal: { handle: default-splitpane }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Window$WindowStyle: {
    default: { titleFont: default-font, background: default-window, titleFontColor: white },
    dialog: { parent: default, stageBackground: dialogDim }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ProgressBar$ProgressBarStyle: {
    default-horizontal: { background: default-slider, knob: default-slider-knob },
    default-vertical: { background: default-slider, knob: default-round-large }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Slider$SliderStyle: {
    default-horizontal: { parent: default-horizontal },
    default-vertical: { parent: default-vertical }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle: {
    default: { font: default-font, fontColor: white }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextField$TextFieldStyle: {
    default: { selection: selection, background: textfield, font: default-font, fontColor: white, cursor: cursor }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.CheckBox$CheckBoxStyle: {
    default: { checkboxOn: check-on, checkboxOff: check-off, font: default-font, fontColor: white }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.List$ListStyle: {
    default: { fontColorUnselected: white, selection: selection, fontColorSelected: white, font: default-font }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Touchpad$TouchpadStyle: {
    default: { background: default-pane, knob: default-round-large }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Tree$TreeStyle: {
    default: { minus: tree-minus, plus: tree-plus, selection: default-select-selection }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextTooltip$TextTooltipStyle: {
    default: {
        label: { font: default-font, fontColor: white },
        background: default-pane, wrapWidth: 150
    }
},
}
```

This is the **default.fnt** inside my **uiskin3.json** file the name goes as**default.fnt.txt** otherwise it will not be found

```
  info face="Droid Sans" size=17 bold=0 italic=0 charset="" unicode=0 stretchH=100 smooth=1 aa=1 padding=0,0,0,0 spacing=1,1
    common lineHeight=20 base=18 scaleW=256 scaleH=128 pages=1 packed=0
    page id=0 file="uiskin.png"
    chars count=96
    char id=32   x=0     y=0     width=0     height=0     xoffset=0     yoffset=16    xadvance=4     page=0  chnl=0 
..................//
```

And the uiskin.png file is also the

I got this error

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: uiskin.json
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:106)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.<init>(Skin.java:83)
    at com.pokedemon.game.selectimages.SelectImages.<init>(SelectImages.java:20)
    at com.pokedemon.game.selectimages.GameClass.create(GameClass.java:19)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:150)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:127)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: uiskin.json
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:797)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:104)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: No Drawable, NinePatch, TextureRegion, Texture, or Sprite registered with name: white
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.getDrawable(Skin.java:323)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.newDrawable(Skin.java:355)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$5.read(Skin.java:590)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:1000)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$1.readValue(Skin.java:469)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:966)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.readNamedObjects(Skin.java:518)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.read(Skin.java:507)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.read(Skin.java:501)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:1000)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$1.readValue(Skin.java:469)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:795)
    ... 6 more

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s


Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: No Drawable, NinePatch, TextureRegion, Texture, or Sprite registered with name: **white**
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.getDrawable(Skin.java:323)
```

Because of that **name: white** I procedeed to check the json file,
changed white to red

```
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$TintedDrawable: {
    dialogDim: { name: white, color: { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 0.45 } },
},
```

to

```
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$TintedDrawable: {
    dialogDim: { name: red, color: { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 0.45 } },
},
```

Mainly to see if the white will change to red and it did, I tried changed rgba values but got the same, so I deleted it, to see the changes

```
    Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: uiskin3.json
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:106)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.<init>(Skin.java:83)
    at com.pokedemon.game.selectimages.SelectImages.<init>(SelectImages.java:21)
    at com.pokedemon.game.selectimages.GameClass.create(GameClass.java:19)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:150)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:127)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: uiskin3.json
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:797)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:104)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Serialization trace:
{}."com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button$ButtonStyle".default.down
down (com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button$ButtonStyle)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readFields(Json.java:908)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$1.readFields(Skin.java:495)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:1073)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$1.readValue(Skin.java:469)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:966)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.readNamedObjects(Skin.java:518)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.read(Skin.java:507)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.read(Skin.java:501)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:1000)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$1.readValue(Skin.java:469)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:795)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: No Drawable, NinePatch, TextureRegion, Texture, or Sprite registered with name: default-round-down
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.getDrawable(Skin.java:323)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.get(Skin.java:156)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$1.readValue(Skin.java:468)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readFields(Json.java:901)
    ... 16 more
```

I removed **com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button$ButtonStyle** the error jumped to **com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle** and so on, but I dont know the reason

This is inside my atlas file but I don't know if I should use it and how

......//
tree-plus
rotate: false
xy: 155, 35
size: 14, 14
orig: 14, 14
offset: 0, 0
index: -1
white
rotate: false
xy: 129, 31
size: 3, 3
orig: 3, 3
offset: 0, 0
index: -1

**GameClass** extends game and it is use to **setScreen(new SelectImages(this));**

Comment: I created a fnt file, and a png was created with it using "hiero", I replaced the name in the json file now is as "default3.fnt" but still having the same issue.

Comment: Based on the error message, evidently the texture atlas you have is missing the region named "white". By the way, there is no need to change the short names like Color to fully qualified names like com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color. Skin recognizes short simple names of all the relevant libGDX classes.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Is this ......// tree-plus rotate: false xy: 155, 35 size: 14, 14 orig: 14, 14 offset: 0, 0 index: -1 white rotate: false xy: 129, 31 size: 3, 3 orig: 3, 3 offset: 0, 0 index: -1 different from the one you are mentioning?   Good to know I can change back to the short names haha

Comment: Is that part of your atlas file?

Comment: Yes, it is those are the last lines in my atlas file